# Failing to execute plantuml in emacs

Tags: emacs, plantuml

I am using `GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)`, on `Windows 10`,  `plantuml 1.4.1`, and the following `.emacs`:

```
(package-initialize)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("MELPA Stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)

(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (plantuml-mode ## flycheck company)))
 '(plantuml-default-exec-mode (quote jar))
 '(plantuml-jar-path "C:\\Users\\tc000210\\AppData\\Roaming\\plantuml.jar"))
```

I execute `plantuml-mode`, and when I try `plantuml-preview` on this PlantUML code:

```
@startuml
A *-- B
@enduml
```

I get the message `error in process sentinel: PLANTUML preview failed: exited abnormally with code 1`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, it works fine on Linux (Fedora 31). Can you process the file from the command line? The [PlantUML documentation](https://plantuml.com/command-line) has forward slashes for the jar path even on Windows - maybe try that?

Comment: Yes, executing from the command line works fine.So, the issue seems at Emacs. May be if I try something different in the configuration?

Comment: I would try setting `plantuml-jar-path` to `"C:/Users/tc000210/AppData/Roaming/plantuml.jar"` using forward slashes: I believe emacs does the right thing with that even on Windows (but what I know about Windows is pretty close to nil).

Comment: @NickD, thanks for the tip, but it did not work either. 
I set the path as you suggested to `"C:/Users/tc000210/AppData/Roaming/plantuml.jar"`, but I got `Writing to process: Invalid argument, PLANTUML`

Answer (score 3):

This is my configuration on Debian Buster with Java11.
You need to replace the path on `plantuml-jar-path`.

```lisp
(use-package plantuml-mode
  :init
    (setq plantuml-default-exec-mode 'jar)
    (setq plantuml-jar-path "/usr/share/plantuml/plantuml.jar")
    (setq org-plantuml-jar-path (expand-file-name "/usr/share/plantuml/plantuml.jar"))
    (setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)
    (add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("plantuml" . plantuml))
    (org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((plantuml . t))))
```